# Can I have null attribute and other attribute at the same tag in XML created by XSD C# generated class?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a bunch of C# classes, which are auto generated from an XSD. Then I generate XML files based on those C# classes. Nothing existing so far.

**The problem:**

The generated XML files are going through validation and the validation requires an extra attribute to all XML tags with `xsi:nil="true"`. Basically the tags should look like :  `<testTag.01 xsi:nil="true" NV="123123" />`, but I can't achieve that in C#.  My code is:

> ```
>      if (myObject.TestTag.HasValue)
>         {
>             t.testTag01 = new testTag01();
>             t.testTag01.Value = myObject.TestTag.Value;
>         }
>         //else
>         //{
>         //    t.testTag01 = new testTag01();
>         //    t.testTag01.NV = "123123";//Not Recorded
>         //}
> ```

This code generates `<testTag.01>SomeValue</testTag.01>` or `<testTag.01 xsi:nil="true"/>`.

If I uncomment the **ELSE**, the result would be: `<testTag.01>SomeValue</testTag.01>` or `<testTag.01 NV="123123" />`.

So I have no idea how to get to the format, which is required by the validation tool. Any ideas ?

P.S.

Here is the auto-generated C# class:

> ///  [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd",
>   "4.0.30319.33440")] [System.SerializableAttribute()]
>   [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
>   [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
>   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true,
>   Namespace="http://www.blabla.org")]
>
> public partial class testTag01 {
>
> ```
> private string nvField;
>
> private SomeEnum valueField;
>
> /// <remarks/>
> [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
> public string NV {
>     get {
>         return this.nvField;
>     }
>     set {
>         this.nvField = value;
>     }
> }
>
> /// <remarks/>
> [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
> public SomeEnum Value {
>     get {
>         return this.valueField;
>     }
>     set {
>         this.valueField = value;
>     }
> } }
> ```

I wouldn't like to alter that part, but I understand it is impossible without doing it. Also I have tried to set SomeEnum to be Nullable. `public SomeEnum? Value`, but is throwing an exception:

```
Cannot serialize member 'Value' of type System.Nullable`1[]. XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode complex types.
```

Comment: Need to see auto-generated classes.  These usually needed to be edited.  You shouldn't need to add code to produce nulls.

Comment: I have put the class. Also I have tried to set the Value to Nullable, but it is throwing an exception. :-(

Comment: This will not work out of the box.  See [**Xsi:nil Attribute Binding Support**: The nil attribute and other attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69.aspx).

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand your data model.  Does your `testTag01` class ever have a `SomeValue` value, or is that there as an artificial requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` doesn't directly support binding to elements that simultaneously have `xsi:nil="true"` along with other attribute values; see [**Xsi:nil Attribute Binding Support**: The nil attribute and other attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69.aspx).

Thus, you need to emit the attribute manually.

If you want to be able to generate an element with no content and two attributes, one named `NV` and the other *always* being `xsi:nil="true"`, you can modify your `testTag01` class to have the `NV` property as well as a synthetic property having the correct namespace and name:

```
public class testTag01 
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string NV { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get { return "true"; } set { } }
}
```

If you *sometimes* want to have `xsi:nil="true"` but at other times want the element to have content corresponding to your `SomeEnum`, you need to do something a bit more complicated, since the `xsi:nil="true"` must be suppressed when the element has content:

```
public class testTag01
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string NV { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get { return SomeEnum == null ? "true" : null; } set { } }

    public bool ShouldSerializeNil() { return SomeEnum == null; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public SomeEnum? SomeEnum { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string SomeEnumText
    {
        get
        {
            if (SomeEnum == null)
                return null;
            return SomeEnum.Value.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            // See here if one needs to parse XmlEnumAttribute attributes
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047125/retrieve-enum-value-based-on-xmlenumattribute-name-value
            value = value.Trim();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                SomeEnum = null;
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    SomeEnum = (SomeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeEnum), value, false);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    SomeEnum = (SomeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeEnum), value, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(An element that simultaneously has both `xsi:nil="true"` and content would be a violation of the [XML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil); hopefully you don't have that.)

Then use it like:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [XmlElement("testTag.01")]
    public testTag01 TestTag { get; set; }

    public static void Test()
    {
        Test(new TestClass { TestTag = new testTag01 { NV = "123123" } });
        Test(new TestClass { TestTag = new testTag01 { NV = "123123", SomeEnum = SomeEnum.SomeValue } });
    }

    private static void Test(TestClass test)
    {
        var xml = test.GetXml();

        var test2 = xml.LoadFromXML<TestClass>();

        Console.WriteLine(test2.GetXml());
        Debug.WriteLine(test2.GetXml());

        if (test2.TestTag.NV != test.TestTag.NV)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("test2.TestTag.NV != test.TestTag.NV");
        }
    }
}
```

The XML output looks like:

> ```
> <TestClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
>   <testTag.01 NV="123123" xsi:nil="true" />
> </TestClass>
> ```

Or

> ```
> <TestClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
>   <testTag.01 NV="123123">SomeValue</testTag.01>
> </TestClass>
> ```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OTHZwO) using these extension methods:

```
public static class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static T LoadFromXML<T>(this string xmlString, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        T returnValue = default(T);

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            object result = (serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))).Deserialize(reader);
            if (result is T)
            {
                returnValue = (T)result;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = null, XmlWriterSettings settings = null, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            settings = settings ?? new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true, IndentChars = "  " }; // For cosmetic purposes.
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
                (serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))).Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As expected there is no solution for that case out of the box, so I improvise a bit and achieved my goal in a post processing logic.

I am parsing the generated XML and if I am looking for a node with xsi:nil attribute, but without NV attribute - I add NV attribute with default value.
Same for the nodes with NV attribute, but no xsi:nil.

Here is the code:

> ```
>         XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();// instantiate XmlDocument and load XML from file
>         doc.Load("somepath.xml");
>
>         //Get the nodes with NV attribute(using XPath) and add xsi:nill to that nodes
>         XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//*[@NV]");
>
>         foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
>         {
>             XmlAttribute nilAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("nil", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
>             nilAttr.Value = "true";
>             node.Attributes.Append(nilAttr);
>         }
>
>         //Get the nodes with xsi:nill attribute(using XPath) and add NV with default value to that nodes
>         XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
>         nsManager.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
>         XmlNodeList nilNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//*[@xsi:nil]", nsManager);
>
>         foreach (XmlNode node in nilNodes)
>         {
>             XmlAttribute nvAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("NV");
>             nvAttr.Value = "7701003";
>             node.Attributes.Append(nvAttr);
>         }
>
>         doc.Save("somepath.xml");
> ```

The upper answer makes totally sense, but since these classes are auto-generated I will do it my way with the post processing, cause if the provider changes the XSD schema, my solution doesn't need any extra work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Actually.  depending on framework versions, etc, you should be able to emit the generated class as a partial.  Then you can include the "always nil attribute" from above into a second class file instead.