# Deserialize XML element with xsi:nil="true" in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to deserialize a XML file with `XmlSerializer` in C#.

The destination class that follows was automatically generated using the xsd utility.

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = true)]
    public partial class location
    {

        private string cityField;

        private string countryField;

        private string stateField;

        private string textField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string city
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cityField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cityField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string country
        {
            get
            {
                return this.countryField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.countryField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string state
        {
            get
            {
                return this.stateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.stateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return this.textField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.textField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine until I reach this portion of the file:

```
<locations>
    <location country="PARAGUAY" city="Ciudad del Este" state="Alto Parana" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <location country="BRAZIL" city="Passo Fundo" state="Rio Grande do Sul" xsi:nil="true"/>
</locations>
```

As [stated in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_2), an element with xsi:nil="true" will be deserialized as a null object, losing all attributes completely. In C# this translates in a null object.

Is there a way to change this behaviour so to have the three properties deserialized?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

**EDIT 1:**

This is the associated namespace:

```
<records xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="structure.xsd">
    (location is within here somewhere)
</records>
```

Comment: It's not well formed xml. The prefix `xsi` is not bound to any namespace.

Comment: It has a specfication, I just omitted it for business privacy. I added a modified version.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [Can I have null attribute and other attribute at the same tag in XML created by XSD C# generated class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903839/can-i-have-null-attribute-and-other-attribute-at-the-same-tag-in-xml-created-by)

Comment: Not really. I'm trying to DEserialize while he's trying to serialize. But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @dbc you were provvidential. I took advice from that answer to come up with a solution. I will post it as soon as I crawl out of this mud pool. >_<  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply want to discard the `xsi:nil` attribute, set [`XmlElementAttribute.IsNullable = false`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable.aspx) in the `[XmlElement]` attribute on the property in the containing class that refers to `location`.
E.g. if you have

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("locations", Namespace = "")]
public class LocationList
{
    [XmlElement("location", IsNullable = true)]
    public List<location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

Manually change it to:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("locations", Namespace = "")]
public class LocationList
{
    [XmlElement("location", IsNullable = false)]
    public List<location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to **bind** to the value of `xsi:nil` while simultaneously binding to the other attribute values, in addition to setting `IsNullable = false`, you may add a manual property along the lines of the one shown in [Can I have null attribute and other attribute at the same tag in XML created by XSD C# generated class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903839/can-i-have-null-attribute-and-other-attribute-at-the-same-tag-in-xml-created-by):

```
public partial class location
{
    bool nil;

    [XmlAttribute("nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public bool Nil
    {
        get
        {
            return nil;
        }
        set
        {
            nil = value;
        }
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeNil() { return nil == true; }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LQOZDQ).

You could also pre- and post-process the XML to rename the `xsi:nil` attribute, as was suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903839/can-i-have-null-attribute-and-other-attribute-at-the-same-tag-in-xml-created-by/32969557#32969557).

Comment: This is exactly the idea I had and that I mentioned in the comments, but it seems to break when it encounters a `<location>` without a xsi:nil, setting null for all subsequent `<location>`s.

Comment: @GigiSan - can you edit your question to include a [mcve] for the problem you're now seeing?  I updated my [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LQOZDQ) and I'm not seeing it.

Comment: sorry for the long wait. I checked the changes I made in the code and found out that I had put `IsNullable = false` on the `Location` class instead of the `Locations` list (actually seemed more logical to me). I also added that `ShouldSerializeNil()` method but did not understand it clearly, is it a standard method of serialization? Anyway, thanks for the help. Since this is similar to what I did and already knew that it could work, I'm flagging this one as answer.

Comment: @GigiSan - the `ShouldSerializeNil()` prevents the [`xsi:nil`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil) attribute from being serialized unless the value is `true`.  Emitting a false value is redundant and generally not done.  As to why it works, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838640/shouldserialize-vs-specified-conditional-serialization-pattern/37842985#37842985).

Answer (score 2):

Try to use custom `XmlReader`. This approach may be useful when there is no possibility to change classes used for deserialization. Also it doesn't require extra memory consumption.

```
public class NilIgnoreReader : XmlTextReader
{
    public NilIgnoreReader(string url) : base(url) { }

    bool isLocation = false;

    public override bool Read()
    {
        bool read = base.Read();

        if (NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && LocalName == "location")
            isLocation = true;

        return read;
    }

    public override string GetAttribute(string localName, string namespaceURI)
    {
        if (isLocation && localName == "nil" &&
            namespaceURI == "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
        {
            isLocation = false;
            return "false";
        }
        return base.GetAttribute(localName, namespaceURI);
    }
}
```

The `NilIgnoreReader` return `false` for `nil` attribute bound to the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace from the `location` elements.

Usage

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Records));
Records record;

using (var reader = new NilIgnoreReader("test.xml"))
    record = (Records)xs.Deserialize(reader);
```

It works for XML like as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<records xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="structure.xsd">
  <locations>
    <location country="PARAGUAY" city="Ciudad del Este" state="Alto Parana" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <location country="BRAZIL" city="Passo Fundo" state="Rio Grande do Sul" xsi:nil="true"/>
  </locations>
</records>
```

and classes like as

```
[XmlRoot("records")]
public class Records
{
    [XmlArray("locations")]
    [XmlArrayItem("location")]
    public Location[] Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    [XmlAttribute("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("state")]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This actually works but being the program a very delicate process I need to do some more tests before deploying it. I will let you know soon. Thanks meanwhile!

Comment: @GigiSan - Yes, of course, test it thoroughly. I'm not sure about the full correctness of this approach.

Comment: I chose to go with dbc's answer cause it was close to what I had in mind already and was almost sure of the result. Given the short time I had I could not quickly test your code with all cases. But anyway it did work in the first cases I tried and I think both solution are equally effective. So thank you very much for your effort. :)