# Compare enum with a List<int>

Tags: c#, list, enums, numbers, compare

In my database I'm saving numbers. Each number has been allocated to a day. For example 1 equals Monday.

In my C# code I have an enum like:

```
enum day { Sunday=0, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday,Saturday  };
```

I want get current day from host and compare it with my database, for checking user access.

What is the best way to compare an enum value with a generic `List<int>`?

I took a look at this topic [How to compare enum and int values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276100/how-to-compare-enum-and-int-values) but it wasn't useful for me.

**UPDATE:** 
I have user access in my program by day and time. I saved the days which can have access to app. the days had saved as integer; so when user wanna login I have to compare integer with enum. because I fetch from database one time, so I have `List<int>` of days.
I dont know is there any better way to do it or not?!

Comment: Could you include more code and/or describe your question better? Why would an enum value ever compare to be equal to a generic list?

Comment: And how/why was the other question not useful?

Comment: As a side note, .NET already has a [DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) enumeration which you can use if you're not doing anything else extra. It also starts at `Sunday = 0`.

Comment: Are you saying you have a list<int> of days a user can access and you want to see it the enum the host provides is in it?

Comment: Ye irani az jense girl :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List< int > allowedDays = new List<int> {0,1,4};

if (allowedDays.Contains((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek))
                // do soemthing
```

Or something like that

Marc

Comment: thanks for spotting the syntax error - would have preferred it to be corrected to List<int> allowedDays = new List<int> {0, 1, 4};   Just think it looks nicer - not that I'm a code snob or anything ;)

Comment: @Iran_Girl what was the problem with `IndexOf` in my comments(I deleted now)

Comment: @mp3ferret sorry but I thought it's better to change until some ones like me in zero level dont make mistake.. THANKS VERY MUCH FOR YOUR EFFICIENT REPLY :)

Comment: @I4V sorry my friend! because I found my answer in @mp3ferret, so I didn't try `IndexOf`. WHY you delete your post :-( it had useful and new codes for me :-(