# How to change return type in Lambda Expression

Tags: c#

I want to query data from sequence (IEnumerable and IQueryable) by nested Interface type, for example,

```
public interface IData
{
    TypeInEnum? Value1 { get; set; }
    string Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class DataModel : IData
{
    public int? Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }

    TypeInEnum? IData.Value1
    {
        get
        {
            return Value1.HasValue ? (TypeInEnum?)Value1.Value : null;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.Commit = variable;
        }
        set
        {
            //ignore enum validation here
            this.Value1 = value.HasValue ? (int?)value.Value : null;
        }
    }
}

public enum TypeInEnum
{
    A = 1,
    B,
    C
}
```

query:

```
//source is IEnumerable<DataModel>
var query = source.Where(item => item.Value1 == 1); //item is DataModel
var query1 = source.Where1(item => item.Value1 == TypeInEnum.A); //item is IData
Assert.IsTrue(query.SequenceEqual(query1));
```

but this only works when Property in class and interface are same type. such as,

when use `Where`, the error is:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Rewriting child expression from type 'System.Nullable<TypeInEnum>' to type 'System.Nullable<System.Int32>' is not allowed, because it would change the meaning of the operation. If this is intentional, override 'VisitUnary' and change it to allow this rewrite.`

use `Select`, the error is:

`System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Nullable<System.Int32>' cannot be used for return type 'System.Nullable<TypeInEnum>'`

I don't know where to add a `Convert`.

all example code [here](https://github.com/runerback/HowToChangeTypeInLambdaExpression)

I have waste time on this for a month...

**Edited**

In my current project, which using `EntityFramework`, there are some basic columns in database of each table, but I found some basic column name are different, for example, `CreatedDateTime` and `DateTimeCreated`. There will be problems when put tables which contains basic column with different name into one `Entity Data Model`. Change these column name in database and project will be difficult and cause some new problems, there are a lot of `svn` branches, and some table are used in many modules. So I create an interface which contains all these basic columns, and change enum field from numeric type (in database) to enum type (in project), and let EF generated class implement this interface, if column name and type are not same, implement property in interface explicitly, therefore impact on the original project can be ignored.

This does solve the problem, but it's difficult to use the interface through EF, such as query data and modified value based on interface then save to database, create some common query extension based on interface. If this is possible, lots of codes can be reduced and the project will be easier to maintain.

Query data from database with same type in both entity model and interface is done, even if the field name is different.

Comment: What's the goal of doing this? I mean, for `Where` for example you can just do `source.Where<IData>(item => item.Value1 == TypeInEnum.A);`, why use expressions and custom visitors?

Comment: @Evk I want to query data from database through EntityFramework, if the property name is different from column name in table, an error will be thrown. So I use a visitor to 'replace' filed name to real one.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try casting the item to `IData` in the `Where` predicate?

```
var query = source.Where(item => item.Value1 == 1); //item is DataModel
var query1 = source.Where(item => ((IData)item).Value1 == TypeInEnum.A); //item is IData
Assert.IsTrue(query.SequenceEqual(query1));
```

The above code works for me with casting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OfType` to filter to only those that are assignable to a type.

Example:

```
var query = source.OfType<DataModel>().Where(item => item.Value1 == 1);
var query1 = source.OfType<IData>().Where(item => item.Value1 == TypeInEnum.A);
```

Answer (score 0):

A technical explanation and fix would be that that you can't compare a Nullable int and a Nullable enum without casting (this is not like [comparing an int and an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276100/how-to-compare-enum-and-int-values)!).

At the end of this post you  will find an example of how you can fix that.

**However**, the more interesting question is why do you have a

class `DataModel` with `public int? Value1` member
that implements
Interface `IData` which declares a `TypeInEnum? Value1` member?

I would argue that if `DataModel` implements `IData` it should also have `Value1` of type`TypeInEnum?` i.e.:

```
public class DataModel : IData
{
    public TypeInEnum? Value1 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

You can find an example for refactored code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ejKoAt)

***As for the technicahl solution:***

Take a look at your code with a casting a fix:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/8MqXnr

```
var query = source.Where(item => item.Value1.HasValue).Where(item => (int)(item.Value1.Value) == 1); //item is DataModel
var query1 = source.Where(item => item.Value1.HasValue).Where(item => item.Value1.Value ==  (int)TypeInEnum.A); //item is IData

var eq = query.SequenceEqual(query1);   
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("results: {0}",eq? "Equal": "Not equal"));
```