# The "==" operator cannot be used for operands of ("enum") or "int" operations

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

When I trying to retrieve data from the database (SQL server/entity framework), I got below error:

> The "==" operator cannot be used for operands of ("enumDropDown") or "int" operations.

and I can't write the query in the controller well, it throws me an error
near`DropdownClassList == 2`.

**Controller:** (i tried)

```
var listaOdbioruNadgodzin = _ecpContext.Karta.Where(x => x.Login == userName && x.DropdownClassList== 2)
```

**Model:**

```
public partial class modelCard
{
    public enumDropDown? DropdownClassList{ get; set; }
}

public enum enumDropDown
{
    test1 = 1,
    test2 = 2,
    test3 =3
}
```

Comment: `x.DropdownClassList == enumDropDown.test2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
var listaOdbioruNadgodzin = _ecpContext.Karta.Where(
               x => x.Login == userName && 
               x.DropdownClassList== enumDropDown.test2)
```

You are currently comparing an enum value with a string "2" while you need to compare it with an enum type.

There are two more options for you (though not recommended and they perform idenitcally to each other [How to compare enum and int values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276100/how-to-compare-enum-and-int-values))

```
x.DropdownClassList == (enumDropDown?)2
```

or

```
(int)x.DropdownClassList == 2
```

Comment: Obviously, we should not convert from `enum` to `int` when we know exactly the value is `enumDropDown.test2`

Comment: Totally agree and that is why I mentioned `though not recommended` in my response. It is an option though and it indicates why the original equality failed.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, sir.

Answer (score 2):

You should compare the property value to a value of the enum:

```
var listaOdbioruNadgodzin = _ecpContext.Karta.Where(x => x.Login == userName && x.DropdownClassList == enumDropDown.test2)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to @juergen d's comment, you should change your code to compare `enumDropDown` instead of `int`.

```
var listaOdbioruNadgodzin = _ecpContext.Karta
             .Where(x => x.Login == userName && x.DropdownClassList == enumDropDown.test2);
```